# How to calculate euclidean distance between two ndarrays in Python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, numpy-ndarray, euclidean-distance

I am trying to calculate the `euclidean distance` between two images. For this I am first getting the `128d` array of the image and then using `cv2.norm()` to get the distance. Below is the code:

```
embedder = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTorch(<model_path>)
embedder.setInput(faceBlob)
vec = embedder.forward()
print(vec)

vec_file = pickle.loads(open(args["recognizer"], "rb").read())
known_vec = vec_file.support_vectors_

for embedding in known_vec:
    print(embedding)
    distance = cv2.norm(vec, embedding)
```

In the above code, I have `vec` which is coming from an image file and `embedding` from `known_vec`. Below is how `vec` and `embedding` looks like:

```
vec:
[[ 1.50953727e-02  2.81099556e-03 -3.50600183e-02 -5.78538561e-03
   2.31029615e-02  1.73964068e-01  3.79475281e-02  1.27083873e-02
  -9.68848541e-02 -1.13846334e-02  1.92795545e-02  7.36472011e-02
   7.79130757e-02 -2.11485863e-01 -6.82436973e-02 -1.64214987e-04
  -2.01231852e-01  2.29396261e-02 -4.34093624e-02  9.49875787e-02
   1.96524531e-01 -1.40022561e-01  1.00606538e-01  3.70812230e-02
  -1.45635298e-02  3.85013111e-02 -8.84107649e-02 -3.15038770e-01
   3.25521380e-02  4.29384746e-02  1.74971391e-02  3.27903479e-02
  -4.76430990e-02  6.02841079e-02  3.60031053e-02 -4.40581292e-02
  -8.15121531e-02  1.46739334e-01  3.19194235e-02 -5.45275658e-02
   3.90344337e-02 -1.47340044e-01 -8.87186751e-02  9.13328975e-02
  -1.33012265e-01 -6.64092153e-02  1.45769000e-01 -4.49066125e-02
  -1.70968711e-01  1.84094254e-02 -1.43186841e-02 -3.82681675e-02
  -9.34342016e-03  3.55955921e-02  6.70149326e-02  1.09950025e-02
   1.09302737e-01  6.81546181e-02 -7.36390129e-02 -1.16702713e-01
  -1.40488185e-02 -2.61708386e-02  2.10996747e-01 -6.54504001e-02
   1.53530702e-01 -8.38626847e-02 -1.86689962e-02 -2.70418124e-03
  -2.32851990e-02  5.15586026e-02 -8.13494101e-02  7.11051449e-02
  -1.19156547e-01  1.64730344e-02  2.14404091e-02 -4.26124930e-02
  -7.58614466e-02  3.41765210e-02  4.33261022e-02  1.71321735e-01
  -1.44580662e-01 -4.46063727e-02  2.88061053e-02  4.15235199e-03
  -1.05133533e-01  1.83968637e-02  1.12521172e-01  5.98449074e-02
   2.27536708e-02 -3.94514054e-02  8.82636383e-02 -8.32060277e-02
  -4.92165126e-02  7.84259290e-03 -1.18784890e-01 -9.60832909e-02
  -4.92453715e-03  1.44542158e-01  3.30348462e-02  2.81231338e-03
   6.14521280e-02 -7.35903298e-03 -7.54322633e-02  1.10058203e-01
   5.87815009e-02  1.78886037e-02 -4.85782837e-03  1.84458613e-01
   3.11982278e-02 -7.37933293e-02 -7.51596317e-02  1.04695961e-01
  -9.72250253e-02 -9.44643840e-02  1.27530798e-01  1.23021275e-01
  -9.76756811e-02 -8.43207240e-02  6.96085840e-02  1.64856598e-01
   2.96653248e-02 -2.89077275e-02 -1.12501364e-02  2.36267108e-03
  -3.10793705e-02  8.10181573e-02  3.76056321e-02  5.94174117e-02]]

embedding:
[ 0.03765839  0.09021743 -0.001356    0.04076054  0.04601533  0.25682124
  0.03684118  0.04658685 -0.0683746   0.0922796   0.04687139 -0.00272194
  0.01932732 -0.16777565  0.06045137 -0.03307288 -0.02232558  0.12863097
  0.06122964 -0.09006073  0.20338912 -0.05094699 -0.05211756  0.07307947
  0.14153366 -0.03110684 -0.11104943 -0.2103712   0.088107    0.09068976
  0.10696387  0.05845631 -0.07577723  0.04438741  0.10031617 -0.02361435
 -0.01955461 -0.08868567  0.11458483 -0.10992806  0.10672607 -0.12679504
  0.01632918  0.07699546 -0.07913689 -0.12192447  0.11415054 -0.0351057
 -0.14725251 -0.13427286  0.10578448  0.06842157  0.01293649 -0.02879749
  0.04028381  0.08853597  0.04816869 -0.01133396 -0.0159949  -0.16353707
 -0.02181644 -0.07351912  0.09002206 -0.15716557  0.09319755 -0.02052106
  0.03212938 -0.03629737 -0.03515568  0.13036096 -0.03792502  0.10754489
 -0.15451996 -0.11948325 -0.04193863 -0.02881463 -0.07436965  0.11885778
  0.0090537   0.10868978 -0.15199617  0.11014692  0.12235526  0.03885943
  0.03852987 -0.01098366  0.10460863  0.01727468  0.04457604  0.01060722
  0.00488355 -0.04175444 -0.10867393  0.00945349 -0.09279638 -0.11769478
  0.03810817  0.09189356 -0.06156022 -0.0081004   0.08123636  0.08515859
  0.0019427   0.05686275 -0.00857953  0.03230546  0.03530128  0.04284313
  0.0120915  -0.00855714 -0.06190326 -0.03082059 -0.13773248 -0.13991699
  0.18191327  0.00246803 -0.08906183 -0.16354702  0.04687581  0.09188556
  0.11612693 -0.06407943  0.01638488 -0.01842222  0.03551267  0.05930701
  0.13821986  0.0852181 ]
```

When I am trying to do `cv2.norm` between these two, I am getting below error:

```
OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\norm.cpp:1081: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function 'double __cdecl cv::norm(const class cv::_InputArray &,const class cv::_InputArray &,int,const class cv::_InputArray &)'
> Input type mismatch (expected: '_src1.type() == _src2.type()'), where
>     '_src1.type()' is 5 (CV_32FC1)
> must be equal to
>     '_src2.type()' is 6 (CV_64FC1)
```

I am not very experienced in `cv2.norm` and `ndarray`. Can anyone please help and suggest some good solutions to calculate the `euclidean` distance. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Norm should do what you need. Looks like the arrays might just have different element [data types](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.types.html)? What is the output of `embedding.dtype` and `vec.dtype`? If that's the case it's an easy fix, just  [convert them](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html).

Comment: @doggie_breath `vec.dtype` is `float32` and `embedding.dtype` is `float64`. How can I convert them.?

Comment: Try `embedding.astype(float32)`.

Comment: @IbrahimYousuf It shows `float32 unresolved reference`

Comment: @IbrahimYousuf Did you mean `embedding.astype('float32')`.?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I missed the quotes.

Comment: @IbrahimYousuf No problem. Even after doing `embedding.astype('float32')`, I am getting error `OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\norm.cpp:1082: error: (-215:Assertion failed) _src1.sameSize(_src2) in function 'cv::norm'`

Comment: @IbrahimYousuf Okay after doing `vec = vec[0]` and then using this `vec` in `norm`, it worked fine.

Comment: Because `embedding` shape is `(1,128)` and shape of vec is `(128,)`

Comment: @IbrahimYousuf What does shape (1, 128) and (128,) means. Can you explain this and also answer this question please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211079/discussion-between-ibrahim-yousuf-and-s-andrew).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cv2.norm` expects the shape of both the arguments to be the same. When you make the call to the function, your two inputs have different shapes. To overcome the problem, you need to reshape one to the same shape as the second.

```
# vec.shape (1,128) This means vec is a 2d array, with 128 values in ist row
# embedding.shape (128,) This mean embedding is a 1d array of 128 values

embedding = np.reshape(embedding, (1,128))
# embedding.shape (1,128) same as vec
distance = cv2.norm(vec, embedding)
```